# What abilities not part of his regular powerset did the Incredible Hulk possess over the years?

Tags: marvel, comics, the-incredible-hulk

The Incredible Hulk over the years has had a fixed powerset. Which are

- Super strength
- High durability
- Healing factor
- A degree of superhuman speed and reflexes
- Some unnatural abilities like viewing astral forms or grabbing and manipulating energy physically
- And his most famous ability, his power increase all of the above via anger

However, on rare occasions he has gained abilities or transformations completely out of the norm and then forever disappeared, such as:

- Flight - Hulk vol 1 #3
- Unipower - Incredible Hulk annual #10 and Captain Universe: Hulk
- Apocalypse enhancement implants - Incredible Hulk #457
- Telekinesis - Savage Hulk #4
- Giant size - Incredible Hulks #635
- Venom symbiote - Absolute Carnage #3
- Adamantium skeleton and claws - Hulkverines #2
- Hammer of Nul form - Fear Itself #1
- Inverted Hulk aka Kluh form - Axis #4

Was there any other such enhancements, transformations or equipment? Please tell me with issue and volume number

Note: interested in information on the 616 incarnation only.